# Create protocol line from string removing \n and \0

Tags: c, string, tcp, char, c-strings

We have to create a text message p2p applicattion with C. We've already done the p2p connection using the TCP interface, but we're having trouble to implement a protocol to send and read messages.

Messages have to be with this format:

Line is the message we want to send and read.
Message will start with 3 chars to indicate the size of the line (ex. 005).

Then it will have the line we want to write or read (ex. hello).

So the message must be a char t[] and for this example it would be 005hello.
No '\n' or '\0' must be send or read, just the size and the string.

We read and write messages using the keyboard using read() and write() call systems, so we know we will have '\n' and '\0' that we want to remove.

We have tried to implement 2 functions that don't work as intendeed. MI_SendLine(int Socket, const char *Line) and MI_ReceiveLine(int Socket, const char *Line).

MI_SendLine must transform the *Line to the described protocol, so the line "hello" will be converted to "005hello", "hello\0\n" will be converted to "005hello", "thx for your time\n" will be "017thx for your time".

For the receiveLine function, we have the same problems, so the code will be omitted.

```
int MI_SendLine(int Socket, const char *Line)
{
    //PROTOCOL TRANSFORMATION
    //3 chars reserved for size of msg
    char message[3 + strlen(Line)];

    int size = strlen(Line);
    int j;
    for(j = 2; j >= 0; j--){
        message[j] = (size % 10) + '0';
        if(size > 0)
            size /= 10;
    }

    int i;
    for(i = 3; i < strlen(Line) + 3; i++){
      message[i] = Linia[i - 3];
    }

    //END PROTOCOL TRANSFORMATION
    return TCP_Send(Socket, message, sizeof(message));
}
```

The TCP function, it has been tested and works correctly

```
int TCP_Sent(int Sck, const char *SeqBytes, int LongSeqBytes)
{
    int bytes_written;
    if((bytes_written=write(Sck,SeqBytes,LongSeqBytes))==-1){
        perror("error en write");
        close(Sck);
        exit(-1);
    }

    return bytes_written;
}
```

We expect the output of "hello\n" to be "005hello" but the actual output is a table of chars full of unknown chars.

Example:
1st message: input "aaa" received message "aaa?" but it's not a ? itself, it's a strange char the contains it.

2n message: input "b" received message "b?.

3rd message: input "ccccc" received message "ccccc" but without the ?

Comment: And what is the output?

Comment: 1st message: input "aaa" received message "aaa?" but it's not a ? itself, it's a strange char the contains it. 2n message: input "b" received message "b?. 3rd message: input "ccccc" received message "ccccc" but without the ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean how to get characters from a string without the new line character and the zero terminating character then here is a demonstrative program that shows how it can be done using the standard C function `strcspn`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const char *s = "thx for your time\n";
    const size_t Size = 3;
    const size_t Base = 10;

    size_t n = strcspn( s, "\n\0" );

    char result[ Size + n ];

    memcpy( result + Size, s, n );

    for ( size_t i = Size; i != 0; i-- )
    {
        result[i-1] = n % Base + '0';
        n /= Base;
    }


    printf( "\"%*.*s\"\n", ( int )sizeof( result ), 
                           ( int )sizeof( result ), 
                           result );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
"017thx for your time"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine. The garbage must be the result of a bug in the receiver. You forgot to append a NUL, or you have some kind of off-by-one error.

As for removing the line feed, just reduce the size and copy one fewer character if the last one is a line feed.

```
int MI_SendLine(int Socket, const char *Line)
{
    size_t len = strlen(Line);    
    if (len > 0 && Line[len-1] == '\n')
        --len;

    if (len > 999) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Message too big!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    char message[3+len];
    message[0] = '0' + len / 100 % 10;
    message[1] = '0' + len / 10 % 10;
    message[2] = '0' + len % 10;
    memcpy(message+3, Line, len);
    return TCP_Send(Socket, message, 3+len);
}
```

or

```
    // sprintf needs space for a NUL even if we don't send it.
    char message[3+len+1];
    sprintf(message, "%03d%s", len, Line);
    return TCP_Send(Socket, message, 3+len);
```

or

```
    char prefix[4];
    sprintf(prefix, "%03d", prefix);
    return TCP_Send(Socket, prefix, 3) + TCP_Send(Socket, Line, len);
```

Note that this doesn't check if there are any line feeds in the middle of the string.